# Audio crackling/distortion at lower volumes

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, headphones

Ever since I've had Windows 10 I've had a problem with the sound that has been accentuated with new headphones and while I find discussions about effects, equalization and Windows 10 problems, I cannot find a fix for this particular behavior.

The symptom is that the lower sounds are heard suddenly louder, or from a certain low volume, all that is higher becomes dimmer, and the consequence is that between both volume ranges there is an intermediate range in which the machine does whatever it does for this effect and the sound at that point is distorted, like mixed with interference.

With relatively loud and stable music there's no problem, but with anything else that is heard lower or at intervals, something as simple as a dialogue is insufferable.

I tried to change the configuration of the headphones from the windows sound options as well as the Sonic Studio that came installed, but it had no effect. Not even removing and setting the loudness equalization fixes this.

EDIT: Since it's been put on hold as too broad I'll try to add detail. The audio device shows as Realtek High Definition Audio and the distortion gets worse and over a broader volume range if I set the system volume low and the headphones' high. If someone knows at least what this effect is, how the lower volume sounds higher and viceversa, if it has a name, I'd appreciate it and might be able to search better because it kind of feels like an effect and not an actual hardware problem except for the distortion

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced similar symptoms on a few lower-powered computers recently. It makes me wonder if modern audio devices are relying more heavily on CPU processing, and a busy CPU not processing the audio information quickly enough results in these symptoms.

In general, I've found success in fully removing the audio devices from device manager and reinstalling the drivers:

1. Open Device Manager as Admin and expand Sound, video, and game controllers.
2. For each audio device, right-click and select Uninstall device.
3. When prompted, choose to delete/uninstall the device drivers.
4. Restart the computer.
5. Either manually find and install the latest audio drivers, or allow Windows to reinstall their preferred drivers.

While your OEM and Windows may offer "guaranteed" drivers, these are often quite out-of-date, relatively speaking. More up-to-date drivers may resolve issues and can often be found at the device or brand site. Realtek offers their HD Audio device drivers here: http://www.realtek.com.tw/Downloads/downloadsView.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=14&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false

A few further thoughts though:

- It is generally considered bad practice to run the output volumes low and relying on greater volume amplification in the output device itself. Instead, set the computer audio volumes higher, and set your output device volumes lower. The less amplification your headphones have to do, the better the quality will be.
- If you are using high-impedance 'cans and expecting high-quality audio from Realtek devices, you won't get it. They may be "HD audio" devices, but only because "HD" sells these days. Good headphones will magnify problems with audio. For normal audio it shouldn't be a problem. You shouldn't be able to hear too much abnormal distortion or static in a normal setup, even with good output devices, but if your standard is very high quality audio, there will be a marked difference.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I haven't uninstalled them but you still pointed me in the right direction. What a ridiculous odissey, I had already checked and tried updating drivers, they all said to be fine and up to date. Eventually I found someone mention some HD audio drivers on the Realtek site, I have installed those and the problem is now gone.

Comment: Cool. I'll add that info to my answer, and then you can mark it as correct.